# WP Control to use to databind to display feed of text "articles" from API?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8, controls, windows-phone

I have an API returning a Json feed containing a list of "articles" comprising of a text paragraph and title. What windows phone 8 XAML control should I use to display said articles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/hh202882%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) with custom ListBox [`ItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

- [Nokia article about ListBox handling](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Listbox_handling_in_Windows_Phone_7)
- [Tutorial from some guy`s blog](http://3water.wordpress.com/2010/07/25/listbox-on-wp7/)

Comment: For better performance on WP7 and WP8, use the `LongListSelector` control. It also has many more features.